Error HotTable renders extra empty column at beginning of table
HotTable puts an empty column at the beginning of the spreadsheet when calling the spreadsheet in vue3.
Above is the code I'm currently using in Vue3. Handsontable / HotTable loads a file that is in xlsx file format. But when loading the table HotTable puts an empty column at the beginning of the table. I am trying to prevent this behavior. I tried using some of the Handsontable parameters to no avail.
<template>
  <div class="table">
    <hot-table 
      ref="hotTableComponent"
      :data="data" :rowHeaders="true" :colHeaders="true" :autoColumnSize="true" 
      licenseKey="non-commercial-and-evaluation" v-bind:lineType="lineType" >
    </hot-table>
  </div>
</template>
  
  <script>
    // import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
    import { HotTable } from '@handsontable/vue3';
    import { registerAllModules, registerAllValidators } from 'handsontable/registry';
    import 'handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css';
    import axios from 'axios';
  
    // register Handsontable's modules
    registerAllModules();
  
    // register Handsontable's validators
    registerAllValidators();

    export default ({
      name: 'SpreadSheet',
      components: {
        HotTable,
      },
      props: {
        lineType: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        }
      },
      data() {
        return {
          height:"auto",
          autoColumnSize:true,
          // copyPasteEnabled: true,
          licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
        };
      },
      methods: {
        async loadSS(fileName, lineType) {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5001/fileContent/${lineType}/?filename=` +   
        fileName);
          this.$refs.hotTableComponent.hotInstance.loadData(res.data);
        }
      },
    });
  </script>

  <style>
  .table {
    padding-left: 1px;
  `}
</style`>


Can you please create a code example in which this behavior can be replicated? Looking at the settings you use, there shouldn't be anything that would cause this.

Thanks for looking at this but this is the code that produces the behavior. Would seeing a snapshot of what it looks like help?

It would be best if you could provide a code example in chosen sandbox, like CodeSandbox, StackBlitz or other.

What about providing a Gist?

Hi, I'm asking for a sandbox version so we can work on an example of the problem being replicable.
